# can any array of string can be stored on localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local

I want to store an array of addresses in the localstorage, e.g

```
addresses["1 doe st, england","2 doe st, england", "3 doe st, england"]
```

I want every time I click on a string it to push to the array of addresses in the localStorage,
I have got this implementation but can only push the first click

```
  const AddRToLocalStorage = (addressText: string): void => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('addresses')) {
      localStorage.setItem('addresses', JSON.stringify(addressText))
    }
  }

.....
   {requestedAddress.map((address, index) => {
                const addressText = `${query}, ${address.line_1}, ${address.district}, ${address.town_or_city}`
                return (
                  <p
                    onClick={() => AddRToLocalStorage(addressText)}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    {addressText}
                  </p>
                )
              })}
```

note that I don't want to have a separate key every time I click on an address to push to the localstorage
so basically I don't want this result
[image]

I want this result[image]

Comment: Load all arrays in a variable and append a new address to it

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a state to store your addresses, and everytime it updates you can update your localStorage with a useEffect() hook

```
const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([]);

useEffect( () => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('addresses')) {
      localStorage.setItem('addresses', JSON.stringify(addresses))
    }
}, [addresses]);

const AddRToLocalStorage = (addressText: string): void => {
    setAddresses([...addresses, addressText]);
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append your selection to the array if address key is already set in localstorage

```
const AddRToLocalStorage = (addressText: string): void => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('addresses')) {
      localStorage.setItem('addresses', JSON.stringify([addressText]));
    } else{
        const addressList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addresses'));
        addressList.push(addressText);
        localStorage.setItem('addresses', JSON.stringify(addressList));
    }
}
```